# Laravel return only the first message and only it's content

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.4, have ajax that calls a post method which calls the register controller (built in) and returns an error in json format, i want only message to be returned and only it's body:
Example:

```
"first_last_name":["First and last names are required"] => only "First and last names are required" to be returned.
```

I am fairly new to Laravel and think here its the validation:

```
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate(); // here i tried  to use ->messages and -> first, but doesn't not seem to work

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

// commented because i don't want auto login and redirect
        //$this->guard()->login($user);

        //return $this->registered($request, $user)
          //              ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

I tried using ->messages() and ->first() but i can't seem to make it work.

Thank you

Comment: You should show more code and what are you trying to do if you want help

Comment: Thank you, updated

Answer (score 0):

You can get every request property using the `get` method.

Example:

`$firstName = $request->get('first_last_name');`

With this you can validate every property separately.

Comment: I don't every property that will exists, in the future may change and i can't prevent it in anyway, that way i am saying that i need the first one from the  errors

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$validator = validator($request->all(), [
   'first_last_name' => 'required',
]);

if($validator->fails()) {
    return response($validator->getMessageBag()->first(), 422);
}

return response('OK', 200);
```